# Indent subsequent lines without hanging indent

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

In Sublime, long lines are wrapped using hanging indent (also known as "reverse indent"). Example:

(I use `"word_wrap": "true"` in my settings).

[image]

Is there way to make long lines wrap without this hanging indentation, i.e. like in Brackets:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my observations, ST always adds one indentation level to lines that were wrapped, if the base scope begins with `source`. (If `indent_subsequent_lines` is set to `true`, ST will indent subsequent word wrapped lines to the level of the line being wrapped and then add the extra level of indentation.)

It seems there is no way to disable hanging indentation in ST for source code. Indeed, this behavior can cause text to be unviewable if it is indented further than the window width - https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/286.

It might be worth logging an issue at https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues to ask the ST devs to consider making an option to disable the hanging indentation.

Comment: Big thanks, Keith. I'm not sure I understand you right (English is not my native language), so here are 2 screenshots. [First](http://i.imgur.com/nNCw2IA.png) and [second](http://i.imgur.com/9O4WYqU.png). Is it expected result or maybe there are some errors in my settings?

Comment: I think your settings are okay (although `true` doesn't need to be quoted after `word_wrap`), but ST sometimes applies settings to a particular view/tab, and then it will ignore the ones set in your preferences file. I would expect your first screenshot to have the wrapped text begin at column 0. Can you close and re-open your `wrapped.js` file, to see if it makes a difference?

Comment: Yes, I understand your idea about "close and reopen". Here are updated screenshots, which were made according "close and reopen" suggestion. [First](http://i.imgur.com/VYpFWpO.png) and [second](http://i.imgur.com/pwuLyNu.png). Top image is the same, it wasn't changed by me. Also here is another version of second screenshot, maybe it will be more convenient for you: http://i.imgur.com/uFOa0SP.png. (I just repeated top image here).

Comment: interesting, it seems I am a little bit wrong - `wrap_width` doesn't seem to make the difference I thought it did. Instead, ST always adds one level of indentation to all word wrapped lines, regardless of the `indent_subsequent_lines`, but if `indent_subsequent_lines` is `true`, it indents to the level of the line being wrapped first, then adds the extra level. Apologies for the misleading information, I'll update my answer.

Comment: I've opened an issue: https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1722